# Problem with "reinterpret_cast" using clang/llvm - error: "..casts away qualifiers"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, reinterpret-cast

i have a problem compiling the following code using clang/llvm:

Header file:

```
inline void**& getvtable(void* inst, size_t offset = 0)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<void***>((size_t)inst + offset);
}

inline const void** getvtable(const void* inst, size_t offset = 0)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<const void***>((size_t)inst + offset);
}


template<typename Fn>
inline Fn getvfunc(const void* inst, size_t index, size_t offset = 0)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Fn>(getvtable(inst, offset)[index]); //Error appears here
}
```

Compiling it with gcc works without errors. 
However, using clang it produces the following error:

`reinterpret_cast from 'const void *' to 'model_t *(*)(void *)' casts away qualifiers`

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const void***>` - [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) detected... In more seriousness, this code has major readability problems, whether it compiles or not. And the compiler message is quite clear that you lost a `const` (which `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away).

Comment: You can't cast away `const` that simply.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow casting between pointers to data (such as `void*`) and pointers to functions. Allowing it is a common extension in most compilers, but they implement it slightly differently as you can see.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The code has not been written by me. But i need to compile it using clang/obfuscator-llvm. Therefore i need it to compile with clang.

I am not that familiar with C++. Any clues / hints how this can be done properly ?

Comment: Whoever wrote the code used compiler-specific behavior. Even if you get it to compile on clang, there is no guarantee whatsoever that it actually still works. And that vtables are apparently messed with in the code (via `reinterpret_cast`) is an even worse sign for compatibility. You can ""fix"" the compiler error by adding a const_cast. But you won't know whether this code works at all (or reliably) without understanding what it does. I would bet money that you run into Undefined Behavior somewhere.

Comment: In other words: If you are unfamiliar with C++, there is no way for you to tell whether your code base would require substantial reworks before it yields a meaningful program when compiled with clang. In that light, you might as well add a `const_cast`, because the current program will almost surely crash and burn anyway once you get it compiled.